# SendCommand(Key) function is not working properly using digitalWrite()

Tags: arduino-uno

I finally figured out to get the unique value from the Car's Head panel input and send the command to the JVC radio as per the input.
Everything seems to be working fine, just the problem is the SendCommand(Key) function is not working properly as expected. It works sometimes, like sometimes I have to click the button twice or thrice to make it work, sometimes it works in the first time and some times it works twice even if i pressed it once...

But every times it shows that the key is there using Serial.println(Key) function... and it has been sent to the function SendCommand(Key) but still it doesn't works every time...

So just want to know that is there anything wrong in the code...

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(7, 5); // RX, TX
String readString;

//JVC Controls
#define VOLUP       0x04
#define VOLDOWN     0x05
#define SOURCE      0x08
#define EQUALIZER   0x0D
#define MUTE        0x0E
#define TRACKFORW   0x12
#define TRACKBACK   0x13
#define FOLDERFORW  0x14
#define FOLDERBACK  0x15
#define UNKNOWN1    0x37
#define UNKNOWN2    0x58

// Connect optocoupler input through a 1k resistor to this pin
#define OUTPUTPIN   8 // D8
// On-board LED, useful for debugging
#define LEDPIN     13 // D13
// Pulse width in µs
#define PULSEWIDTH 527
// Address that the radio responds to
#define ADDRESS 0x47
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(57600);
  //Serial.setTimeout(2000);
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(OUTPUTPIN, OUTPUT);    // Set the proper pin as output
}

unsigned char GetInput(int number, int prevNumber)
{
  if(number == 143)
    return TRACKBACK;
    else if(number == 140)
    return TRACKFORW;
    else if(number == 142)
    return FOLDERBACK;
    else if(number == 139)
    return FOLDERFORW;
    else if(number == 1)
    return VOLUP;
    else if(number == 255)
    return VOLDOWN;
    else if(number == 60)
    return MUTE;
    else if(prevNumber == 52 && (number == 32 || number == 37 || number == 38))
    return SOURCE;

    return 0;
}

 int prevNumber=0;
void loop() {

  while (mySerial.available()) {
    delay(10); 
    int number = mySerial.read();
    mySerial.flush();
      unsigned char Key = GetInput(number, prevNumber);  // If any buttons are being pressed the GetInput() function will return the appropriate command code
      if (Key) {  // If no buttons are being pressed the function will have returned 0 and no command will be sent
        Serial.println(Key);
        SendCommand(Key);
    }
    prevNumber = number;

}
}




// Send a value (7 bits, LSB is sent first, value can be an address or command)
void SendValue(unsigned char value) {
  unsigned char i, tmp = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(value) * 8 - 1; i++) {
    if (value & tmp)  // Do a bitwise AND on the value and tmp
      SendOne();
    else
      SendZero();
    tmp = tmp << 1; // Bitshift left by 1
  }
}
// Send a command to the radio, including the header, start bit, address and stop bits
void SendCommand(unsigned char value) {
  unsigned char i;
  Preamble();                         // Send signals to precede a command to the radio
  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {           // Repeat address, command and stop bits three times so radio will pick them up properly
    SendValue(ADDRESS);               // Send the address
    SendValue((unsigned char)value);  // Send the command
    Postamble();                      // Send signals to follow a command to the radio
  }
}
// Signals to transmit a '0' bit
void SendZero() {
  digitalWrite(OUTPUTPIN, HIGH);      // Output HIGH for 1 pulse width
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);         // Turn on on-board LED
  delayMicroseconds(PULSEWIDTH);
  digitalWrite(OUTPUTPIN, LOW);       // Output LOW for 1 pulse width
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);          // Turn off on-board LED
  delayMicroseconds(PULSEWIDTH);
}
// Signals to transmit a '1' bit
void SendOne() {
  digitalWrite(OUTPUTPIN, HIGH);      // Output HIGH for 1 pulse width
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);         // Turn on on-board LED
  delayMicroseconds(PULSEWIDTH);
  digitalWrite(OUTPUTPIN, LOW);       // Output LOW for 3 pulse widths
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);          // Turn off on-board LED
  delayMicroseconds(PULSEWIDTH * 3);
}
// Signals to precede a command to the radio
void Preamble() {
  // HEADER: always LOW (1 pulse width), HIGH (16 pulse widths), LOW (8 pulse widths)
  digitalWrite(OUTPUTPIN, LOW);       // Make sure output is LOW for 1 pulse width, so the header starts with a rising edge
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);          // Turn off on-board LED
  delayMicroseconds(PULSEWIDTH * 1);
  digitalWrite(OUTPUTPIN, HIGH);      // Start of header, output HIGH for 16 pulse widths
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, HIGH);         // Turn on on-board LED
  delayMicroseconds(PULSEWIDTH * 16);
  digitalWrite(OUTPUTPIN, LOW);       // Second part of header, output LOW 8 pulse widths
  digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);          // Turn off on-board LED
  delayMicroseconds(PULSEWIDTH * 8);
  // START BIT: always 1
  SendOne();
}
// Signals to follow a command to the radio
void Postamble() {
  // STOP BITS: always 1
  SendOne();
  SendOne();
}
```

Comment: Won't you timings be off because you are doing two digtalWrite before delaying for the number of pulse widths.  Does that matter?

Comment: Hi... thanks for helping... but the thing is I dont understand this coding.. I am using it for my car... so it will be helpful if you can help me with the exact code... then I will run it and then let you know...

Comment: If you want to use the code you are going to need to understand it.  You are calling `delayMicroseconds(PULSEWIDTH * 16);` which means you are waiting for a very specific amount of time eg 8432 microseconds.  I assume your receiver will need a delay of 8432us not 8479us because you have called the function `digitalWrite()` twice before delaying.  So the question is do you need to reduce the delay by X microseconds because of the calls to `digitalWrite()`?  (I don't know what X is)

Comment: Then what should i do... ? Should i remove the function delayMicroseconds or reduce the value in that or add delayMicroseconds after each digitalWrite function... ?

Comment: You need to read the requirements of the receiver and see what you should do.